# Using imported solidity interfaces with brownie

Tags: solidity, brownie, interfaces

It seems like `brownie compile` doesn't produce ABI for an imported interface.
I would like to use OpenZeppelin IERC20 interface.
Here is the setup:

brownie-config.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.4.0

compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.4.0'
```

interfaces/IERC20.sol

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import {IERC20} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/interfaces/IERC20.sol";
```

Someplace in scripts:

```
token = interface.IERC20(contract_address)
```

I expect that after running: `brownie compile -all` IERC20's ABI will be created and placed in build/interfaces/IERC20.json. This doesn't happen, as a result python script fails.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: This is currently an issue with brownie: https://github.com/eth-brownie/brownie/issues/936

if you know how to fix it, that would be great!